# Change Sim Card Number Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sim-card

I have a new Galaxy S3 which I ported my old number to from across networks. I now have my old number, but `Settings -> Status` still shows the old number!

Is there any way to change this on ICS or the Galaxy S3? I also have access to an old HTC Desire running Cyanogenmod 7 if that helps :D

Comment: When did you port the old number? it depends on your carrier in porting the number over, it could take 24 hours up to a week, I would think. BTW What carrier? If its USA orientated, then that would be best answered by someone else as am European :)

Comment: BTW to clarify you stated *which I ported my old number to from across networks. I now have my old number, but Settings -> Status still shows the old number!* Did you mean the new number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sony Xperia Arc S, changing the "my number" in contact list?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24060/sony-xperia-arc-s-changing-the-my-number-in-contact-list)

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the "My Number" field then I answered the question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24060/sony-xperia-arc-s-changing-the-my-number-in-contact-list/24920#24920).

> The "My Number" isn't actually stored on the phone, it is stored on
>   your sim card. Stock android can't edit this data. CyanogenMod can, so
>   can iPhones and BlackBerrys. If you can get your hands on one of these
>   then just pop your sim into it and edit the "My Number" field and Bobs
>   your uncle.

Comment: +1 - I had to use a loaner Blackberry to change mine. Technically, this field on the SIM card is called your [MSISDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSISDN).