# Sony Xperia Arc S, changing the "my number" in contact list?

Tags: sony-xperia-arc

I've recently purchased a second-hand phone and my number is different than the one shown. How can I either remove it or change it? I've tried to add a field to it but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried doing a factory reset?

Answer (score 1):

If you have not done a Factory Reset, the Android operating system is still in the same state as it was when whoever owned the phone installed it. Do the following to completely wipe the phone and thereby force the phone to recognize what phone# is relevant for the sim card inserted:

- From the main home screen, tap menu
- Tap Settings, then Privacy
- Tap Factory data reset
- Tap Reset phone
- Enter your password if required, then tap Erase everything to confirm

Answer (score 0):

The "My Number" isn't actually stored on the phone, it is stored on your sim card. Stock android can't edit this data. CyanogenMod can, so can iPhones and BlackBerrys. If you can get your hands on one of these then just pop your sim into it and edit the "My Number" field and Bobs your uncle.

Comment: You're approaching the problem from the wrong angle. The number shown is whoever had the phone before, which means Android likely needs to be wiped to reset it.

Comment: No it's not. The My Number is pulled from the sim card that is in the phone. Sometimes the number on the sim card is incorrect due to things like number porting. The easiest way to fix this is to just pop the sim into a phone that supports editing of the number. I think the network operator can resend the information to the sim as well but I'm not sure how successful that is.

Comment: I never said anything else. However, you're saying that it's pulled from the SIM *every time that screen is loaded* or what?